# 'Play' button in Manipulation and slow evaluations

Tags: manipulate, animation

I'm trying to create animation of some discrete process using Manipilate:

`Manipulate[**Some graphics based on very slow computations, each step is calculated slowly then the previous**], {Step, 1, 1000, 1}]`

It works fine if I move Step slider with the mouse.

But if I click the 'Play' button, animation starts but a lot of steps are missing. For example, I see the picture corresponding the 1st step, then the 13th, then 51st... And sometimes I even get '$Aborted'.

Manipulate options like `ContinuousAction -> False` don't make any change.

How can I make Manupulate display all the steps, one by one, with "Play' button?

Comment: Short way should be to adjust `AnimationRate`: `{step, 1, 1000, 1, AnimationRate -> 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]`

Comment: But as I said computation time is different for each step, so it's impossible to find proper constant AnimationRate.

Comment: Better use Animate here and let it calculate all steps in advance

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks, it will work for sure, but in this case we need a lot of memory to store each step data :(

Comment: Converting the graphics to a bitmap may help if the number of graphical objects is high.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries thanks, it's not entirely what I wanted, but it looks good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the option `DisplayAllSteps -> True` in [`Animate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Animate.html):

```
(* plot with a random lag *)
plot[r_] := (Pause[RandomReal[]]; Plot[Sinc[r/10 x], {x, 0, 10}])

Animate[plot[z], {z, 1, 50, 1}, DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

This code fails with an `$Aborted` if the rendering takes more than five seconds, because of the default Dynamic timeout.  [Michael](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) explained how to use [`DynamicEvaluationTimeout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicEvaluationTimeout.html) to solve this as follows:

```
(* plot with a longer lag *)
plot[r_] := (Pause[6]; Plot[Sinc[r/10 x], {x, 0, 10}]);

Style[
  Animate[plot[z], {z, 1, 50, 1}, DisplayAllSteps -> True],
  DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 100
]
```

Comment: In this case I get $Aborted when Step is rather big. The problem was discussed here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/0lsxg6yOHZU

Comment: @Epik17 I believe that only happens when the rendering lag is quite high; if it is that high this won't really count as an "animation" at that point.  Nevertheless there should be a work-around for that; let me see if I can find it.

Comment: I will be grateful if you find it.

Comment: @Epik17 Mr.Wizard, perhaps you're thinking of [`DynamicEvaluationTimeout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicEvaluationTimeout.html)?  I think that's probably the sourced of the aborted calculations. -oops, that's available only in V8+

Comment: @MichaelE2 Perhaps that is a solution you should answer with.  Anyway, I'm annoyed that I don't know a way to do this; adding `SynchronousUpdating -> False` makes `DisplayAllSteps -> True` ineffective.  I don't think I've ever attempted this particular problem before ("animating" a very slow operation).

Comment: FYI: It's there in V7, perhaps: http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/note/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#138999801

Comment: @MichaelE2 With `DynamicEvaluationTimeout` I'm not getting $Aborted, but a lot of steps is missing during animation.

Comment: @Epik17 `plot[r_] := (Pause[6]; Plot[Sinc[r/10 x], {x, 0, 10}]); Style[
 Animate[plot[z], {z, 1, 50, 1}, DisplayAllSteps -> True],
 DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 100
 ]` works for me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That even works in version 7.  Post an answer!  How did you figure out that option works in `Style`?

Comment: Read the link to the V9 documentation in my initial comment.  I was surprised it was a `Style`, too.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It does leave *Mathematica* very laggy however, which is why the timeout is less by default of course.  Is there any way to get `DisplayAllSteps -> True` behavior, even manually, while using method `"Queued"` or `SynchronousUpdating -> False`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I see now; thanks.

Comment: Feel free to incorporate it.  `DisplayAllSteps` is your contribution.  I've got to take my daughter to school now and start my day.  I'll think about other ways.

Comment: @MichaelE2 My code based on your `plot[r_] := (Pause[6]; Plot[Sinc[r/10 x], {x, 0, 10}]); Style[ Animate[plot[z], {z, 1, 50, 1}, DisplayAllSteps -> True], DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 100 ]` works! Thank you! Mr.Wizard thanks for your help too!